# Field distribution of users: what kind of expertise do we have on our SE site

Tags: discussion

It would be nice to know, more or less, what is the expertise base that we have on Engineering SE.

Instead of each person giving a separate answer akin to "Hi, I'm an X engineer", where X is their expertise, perhaps we can set it up like a poll:  one separate answer per expertise and people upvote it if they have the same expertise.

For example, i'm an applied mathematician.  So i would post the answer: "applied mathematics".  If you are also in applied math, you would upvote my answer instead of duplicating it.  If you are something else that isn't already listed, answer with your particular expertise.

Answer (score 8):

I am in Mechanical Engineering. Upvote here if you are as well.

Comment: Even ME could be broken down into a few more categories.

I'm a ME with concentration in controls and have done a lot of work with Simulink. Other than what I took in school I really have no knowledge of a lot of other ME realms.

Comment: @JedF same here, actually! :-) I thought about splitting it up further, but I thought it would get too fragmented since one person might not feel that they fit exactly into the more specialized category created by someone else.

Answer (score 8):

Civil Engineers should upvote here.

Comment: I may add myself as +0.5 point. I'm actually a control engineer developing control devices for civil engineering, so, with Civil Engineers being my customers I must understand what they do, to know what they need my devices to do.

Comment: This also includes Structural Engineers.

Answer (score 6):

I'm an Electrical Engineer. Upvote if you are too.

Comment: I'm including any bit of electronics and electrical engineering, not just power here.

Comment: An EE undergrad and then Physics.

Comment: I'm an EE too! Concentration in analog/RF electronics.

Comment: @pikafu RF, nice. I do some rf work too, mostly DSP type stuff on DAQ boards.

Answer (score 2):

I am in Chemical Engineering. Upvote if you are a student, technician, graduate or practicing in the same field.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an environmental engineer, with a background in process engineering (not CE)

Answer (score 2):

I have also done some control engineering. Upvote here if you are into controls, instrumentation, supervisory control or related fields.

Answer (score 2):

Experimental Physicist

Upvote here if you are also a physicist.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical Engineering with an emphasis on computational and continuum mechanics by education, Systems Engineer for Spacecraft Survivability by trade.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote here if you are also a geotechnical engineer.

I am a civil engineer, so I upvoted the CE answer above, but my specialty is as a geotechnical engineer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Mining Engineer (as in coal and rock, not data... we'll I've done some data mining internally but nothing major). Any others representing the dirty of the industry?

Answer (score 1):

Materials engineering. Body must be at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Applied Mathematics.... Upvote here if you are as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am a high school student (learning AutoCAD and general engineering). Upvote here if you are a secondary school (i.e. high school) student as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a designer on structural and mechanical systems. I'm not a licensed engineer, but I work with licensed structural and civil engineers.

Upvote here if you are also a designer of engineered systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Manufacturing engineer, with expertise in CNC machining, carbon fiber composites, and manual machining.